# Android: How To include project in Settings.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Following my project directory structure:

```
dev/
   android/
           apps/ 
                project2
   project1
```

I want to include project 1 in my project 2. So I am trying to add this project in my settings.gradle file. Following is the content of my settings.gradle file:

```
include ‘:project2', ‘dev:project1'
project('../../..project1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, ‘:project1’)
```

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project('../client/project1')
}
```

When I try to build my project it gives me this error:

```
Error:Project with path '../../.. project1' could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using following code in settings.gradle

```
include ‘:project2', ‘dev:project1'
project(':project1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, ‘../../../project1’)
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':project1')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the `settings.gradle` file placed at root folder:

`include ':dev:project1', ':dev:android:apps:project2'`

Comment: my settings.gradle is in project 2 folder